# Jmeter integration with Keycloak - Login in application

Tags: jmeter

I have an application which is authorized with keycloak (using openid).When i used to only application URL then login page came. In address bar 'state' & 'nonce' value is coming. But while recording in Jmeter 5.1 I am not able to find these values in response of which request. If i can find the exact request so i can create Regex in that request and store that values in variable for further use. Please help me for this case. Thank you in advanced.

```
App url - http://{ServerDNS}/{tagname}/#
Redirected URL once used App URL - https://{ServerDNS:Port}/auth/realms/{keycloakNmae}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=id_token%20token&client_id=oauth2&state=yaFY1QJATZxm4LHJoobGu9YEN9aS95zlGWbuTG5B&redirect_uri={APP_URL}&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20voucher&nonce=yaFY1QJATZxm4LHJoobGu9YEN9aS95zlGWbuTG5B
```

Here state & nonce values are -

```
state=yaFY1QJATZxm4LHJoobGu9YEN9aS95zlGWbuTG5B
nonce=yaFY1QJATZxm4LHJoobGu9YEN9aS95zlGWbuTG5B
```

I didn't find these values in response of any request. these values are coming in redirect url before providing user credentials.

Again Thank you.

Here state & nonce values are -

```
state=yaFY1QJATZxm4LHJoobGu9YEN9aS95zlGWbuTG5B
nonce=yaFY1QJATZxm4LHJoobGu9YEN9aS95zlGWbuTG5B
```

I didn't find these values in the response of any request. these values are coming in redirect URL before providing user credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [OpenID Connect Core 1.0 incorporating errata set 1](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)

```
+--------+                                   +--------+
|        |                                   |        |
|        |---------(1) AuthN Request-------->|        |
|        |                                   |        |
|        |  +--------+                       |        |
|        |  |        |                       |        |
|        |  |  End-  |<--(2) AuthN & AuthZ-->|        |
|        |  |  User  |                       |        |
|   RP   |  |        |                       |   OP   |
|        |  +--------+                       |        |
|        |                                   |        |
|        |<--------(3) AuthN Response--------|        |
|        |                                   |        |
|        |---------(4) UserInfo Request----->|        |
|        |                                   |        |
|        |<--------(5) UserInfo Response-----|        |
|        |                                   |        |
+--------+                                   +--------+
```

and into [ID Token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)

> `nonce`
>   String value used to associate a Client session with an ID Token, and to mitigate replay attacks. The value is passed through unmodified from the Authentication Request to the ID Token. If present in the ID Token, Clients MUST verify that the nonce Claim Value is equal to the value of the nonce parameter sent in the Authentication Request. If present in the Authentication Request, Authorization Servers MUST include a nonce Claim in the ID Token with the Claim Value being the nonce value sent in the Authentication Request. Authorization Servers SHOULD perform no other processing on nonce values used. The nonce value is a case sensitive string.

and into [Nonce Implementation Notes](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#NonceNotes)

> The nonce parameter value needs to include per-session state and be unguessable to attackers. **One method to achieve this for Web Server Clients is to store a cryptographically random value as an HttpOnly session cookie** and use a cryptographic hash of the value as the nonce parameter. In that case, the nonce in the returned ID Token is compared to the hash of the session cookie to detect ID Token replay by third parties. A related method applicable to JavaScript Clients is to store the cryptographically random value in HTML5 local storage and use a cryptographic hash of this value.

So you could obtain this `nonce` value either from your browser [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or from its [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Just in case check out [OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) for better understanding of the concept.